# Image Classification - Loss - Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am training Images for classification task. I used One hot encoding, categorical crossentropy for loss, and Adam for optimizer.

While training, I faced this situation,

```
Epoch 1/10
10/10 [==============================] - 591s 57s/step - loss: 57984075590.2520 - accuracy: 0.0450 - val_loss: 21337043107840.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.0308

Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from inf to 21337043107840.00000, saving model to model.h5
Epoch 2/10
10/10 [==============================] - 578s 58s/step - loss: 13186267529728372.0000 - accuracy: 0.0166 - val_loss: 1072926192530620416.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00

Epoch 00002: val_loss did not improve from 21337043107840.00000
Epoch 3/10
10/10 [==============================] - 568s 57s/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0246 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.4820

Epoch 00003: val_loss did not improve from 21337043107840.00000
```

How the loss is very high, and in epoch-3, the loss goes to nan.

I checked there is no nan values in the dataset, even after normalization

How to solve this, thanks

Comment: Probably your loss gets so high that it overflows.

Comment: Without code or details this is impossible to answer.

Comment: How do you expect to answer while you didn't share your code?